# Как выводить картинки горизонтально в html (jsp)

Tags: css, html5

Ниже пример кода в `jsp`.
В этом примере они выводятся вертикально.

Но как в `jsp` (`html`) сделать так, чтобы картинки печатались горизонтально?

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="col col_14 product_gallery">
            <c:forEach items="${allProducts}" var="product">
                <img src="/product/image?fileName=${product.picture}" width="150">
                <li> ${product.name}<a href="/getProductById?id=${product.id}">get</a>
            <h3>Ut eu feugiat</h3>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто родителю задай display: flex; и если нужно равномерно распределить пространство между картинками то еще и justify-content: space-between/around;

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

Расположение изображений на странице не относится ни к Java, ни к JSP. Это вопрос выбора правильных тегов, их относительного расположения и стилей.

```css
.product_gallery div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 145px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="col col_14 product_gallery">
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2yQ0.png">
      <span>Ut eu feugiat</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2yQ0.png">
      <span>Ut eu feugiat</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2yQ0.png">
      <span>Ut eu feugiat</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

У вас используется блочный тег h3, который всегда занимает всю ширину родительского блока, и почему-то используются теги элемента списка (li) без самого списка (ul/ol). Они и мешают изображениям выстроится в одной строке.

Comment: img сам по себе inline-block, автор чего то накосячил

Comment: @МаксимЛенский ниже кода написано, с чем он накосячил.

Comment: да да .. прости ... щас  плюсик поставлю

Comment: Спасибо всем огромное

Comment: @Vigen.hovhannisyan если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).